# Error with EPPlus Loading DataTable to ExcelWorksheet

Tags: vb.net, epplus

I have the following code, where I use a *SqlDataAdapter* to fill a *DataTable*. I'm using *EPPlus* to create an Excel Package and worksheet, but when I call *LoadFromDataTable*, the worksheet is not being populated with data from the data table. I'm not sure wherein lies the problem, but I'm stumped.

```
Protected Sub btnExportToExcel_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
    Dim da As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter("usp_StoredProcedure", sQLConnString)
    da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("param1", "text")
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("param2", "text")
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("param3", "text")
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("param4", "text")
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("param5", "text")
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("param6", "text")
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("param7", "text")
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("param8", "text")

    Try
        da.Fill(dt)
    Catch ex As Exception
        ' Do Stuff
        Return
    End Try

    If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        Using pck As ExcelPackage = New ExcelPackage()
            Dim ws As ExcelWorksheet = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("SheetName")
            ws.Cells("A1").LoadFromDataTable(dt, True)
            Response.ClearContent()
            Response.BufferOutput = True
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + String.Format("FileName-{0:yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss}.xlsx", DateTime.UtcNow))
            Response.BinaryWrite(pck.GetAsByteArray())
            Response.Flush()
            Response.End()
        End Using
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you check the `DataTable` to see if it was filled in debug mode?

Comment: Yes, the DataTable is filled and I visually verified its contents in debug mode. There are 6 columns, and row count can vary between 1 and 100.

Comment: When you open the excel file does `SheetName` tab exist?

Comment: @Ernie It's not actually creating the excel file. Calling LoadFromDataTable does not fill the worksheet with the data from the DataTable.

Comment: @CodyHitson Are you saying that you are getting an excel file with a single tab called "SheetName" that is empty?  Or are you getting nothing at all from the call to `BinaryWrite`?  If it is the former, I would image the dt is empty but if you are sure it is not you may have to step through the Epplus code to figure out what is going on.  If it is the latter, that could be something with the`Response` object itself if you are sure pck has content (try saving to a local file using `SaveAs()`).